# How to apply a calculation to groupby rows in a dataframe and append the results to the bottom of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, append

I am trying to append the results of a simple calculation within a dataframe. I would like to groupby the Year and then calculate Revenue less Tax to get a new set of records called Net Revenue.

```html
import pandas as pd


data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010],
        'item': ['Revenue', 'Revenue', 'Revenue', 'Tax', 'Tax', 'Tax'],
        'value': [11, 8, 10, 3, 2, 3]}
dfRev = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'item', 'value'])

print dfRev
```

```
   year     item  value
0  2010  Revenue     11
1  2011  Revenue      8
2  2012  Revenue     10
3  2011      Tax      3
4  2012      Tax      2
5  2010      Tax      3
```

I would like to add to the bottom like this.

```
   year     item  value
0  2010  Revenue     11
1  2011  Revenue      8
2  2012  Revenue     10
3  2011      Tax      3
4  2012      Tax      2
5  2010      Tax      3
6  2010 Net Revenue   8
7  2011 Net Revenue   5
8  2012 Net Revenue   7
```

My actual data has more headings i.e.ORIGIN,Product,Country,item,Month, Value

I would need to pivot so that it groups by ORIGIN,Product,Country, Month. then throws item to the column and Value as values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a pivot:

```
#reshape so now you have a col for Tax and a col for Revenue
pivot = dfRev.pivot('year', 'item', 'value')
#perform the calculation
pivot.loc[:, 'Net Revenue'] = pivot.Revenue - pivot.Tax
#and then bring it back to the original shape
dfRev = pivot.stack().reset_index().sort_values(by='item')

print dfRev
   year         item   0
2  2010  Net Revenue   8
5  2011  Net Revenue   5
8  2012  Net Revenue   8
0  2010      Revenue  11
3  2011      Revenue   8
6  2012      Revenue  10
1  2010          Tax   3
4  2011          Tax   3
7  2012          Tax   2
```

Comment: I struggled to apply your method as i have multiple columns in my actual file, sorry for not providing all the detail. So i went with the pivot_table method, which seemed simplier for me to apply. Also, the .sort_values(by= 'item') didnt work for me, so i dropped it, as not required anyway.                  pivot = pd.pivot_table(dfResultFinal, values = 'Value',index =['ORIGIN','Product','Country','Business','Existing','Month'],columns= 'Measure Detail')

Comment: after making the calculations once pivoting and trying to then unpivot, I had the problem that the 'value' name was dropped and replaced with a 0? any thoughts.    dfResultFinal= pivot.stack().reset_index()

Comment: maybe you can post a sample of the actual data? Seems like you want to do something more than what was in your original question. Hard do say without seeing what youre talking about.